# Change today date with "-1 day" after 15 times in loop

Tags: php, loops, date

I've a curious question, I know: in a Wordpress loop, like this:

```
<?php if (have_posts() ) while (have_posts() ) :the_post(); ?>
```

I wanna show today date, but not with with "the_time" function, but in this way:

```
<?php setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ita', 'it_IT.utf8'); echo strftime('%d %B %Y'); ?>
```

Today date appears for all posts, and that's OK.

Now, I wanna show "-1 day" date after 15 loops (or 15 posts), and after 15 -1 again, and so on every 15.
How i can do it?

Thanks! ;-)

Comment: use the second parameter of stftime: `echo strftime('%d %B %Y', time() - 60 * 60 * 24);`

Comment: Mhhh... Can you explain me better, perhaps with an example? :-)

Comment: http://php.net/strftime for "examples", e.g. RTFM?

Comment: Do you want to show posts from the previous day after 15 posts? or do you want to just show the previous date?

Comment: No! Simply, after 15 posts, I wanna show the day before date. For example, on first 15 posts, I wanna show the today date (2016/01/22), and after 15 the yesterday date (2016/01/21), and after 15 the three days ago date and so on!

Comment: Without relevance to the shown posts? That doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I need to use for a category template apart!
It is not important to the effective date of the post: I need that dates decrease of one day every 15 :-)

Comment: Well then get the current timestamp before the loop, and increase a counter variable inside the loop. If that reaches 15, reset it, and subtract one day from your timestamp value.

Comment: 'Cause I'm not very practical, and this is why I'm asking for help, can you give me an example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking what I think you are asking here's an example of getting the day before every 15th iteration of an array of dates:

```
   //Untested
   $i = 0;
   foreach($dates as $date){
       if(($i % 15) == 0){//if $i is a multiple of 15
            $display_date = strftime('%d%b%y', $date ."- 1 day");
            echo $display_date; 
         }
   $i++;
   }
```

Comment: Mhhh... There's someting wrong (syntax error?) here:
`if($i % 15 = 0){`

Comment: Mhhhh...Why I receive

`invalid argument supplied for foreach()` ?

Comment: well, you need to pass this a valid array of dates. This is just an example of how you could solve your problem, not the solution.